# How Can I cut img background and disable default responsive behavior?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I disable responsive background img behavior ?

My background img in larger screen is like this :

[image]

And I want this behavior when I resize screen (small screens). (I want that the img will be cut automatically) : does a css property exist for this ?

[image]

My code is :

```
.bg {
 background-image: url(assets/images/bg.png, 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

  <div class="container-full bg">
   <div class="container">
  <div>My content....</div>
  </div>
```

I am in bootstrap project , and my background img is responsive, how can I disable this please ?

Comment: There are many helpful tutorials to display a background image for your cases. Have you dealt with css before?
Try out a tutorial of your choice. Here is one for you: [Responsive Full Background Image Using CSS](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/responsive-background-image/) I recommend to solve the problem yourself before you get a copy and paste answer.

Comment: Yes i had seen many tutorials , I dont found what i want :(

Comment: `I want that the img will be cut automatically` do you mean the image should be like 100% height and only cutted on the sides? Where do you want to cut your background image?

Comment: If you share the relevant HTML and CSS part of your code, we can help you.

Comment: See my updated question (i added the code), by default boostrap resize my background img and make it responsive, i want to disable this for my container full background ! I want to crop the img like picture above

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick cutout. You can position the image `left`, `center` or `right`. The image will be trimmed automatically.
You can define the height for yourself.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  background-image:  url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtaEI.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
   <div>My content....</div>
</div>
```

### edit

Please be aware that you need semicolons in .css after each declaration

your code:

```
 .bg {
   background-image: url(assets/images/bg.png, 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

need to look like this:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("assets/images/bg.png"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesnt working, try to open your code in the snipet and resize window , you wil see that the img background is responsive :(

Comment: In my opinion you see exactly the middle section as in your question. The image will be trimmed automatically. The height is absolute, the side length relative.

Comment: I think this problem with bootstrap also , i dont want that my background img been responsive :( your code is responsive when i resize window , there is no cut :(

Comment: I cannot understand that. For me the sides are trimmed. The middle part of the picture is the same. Remember that your background image has very small dimensions. This can lead to distortions. So the small picture is constantly visible on large screens...